# php call time pass by reference

Tags: php, xls

Im working on a project which uses **[ole_pps_root](http://www.turbolead.com/code-comments/turbolead/turbolead/ole_pps_root.html)** class to export data to XLS.
We are using PHP 5.2.14, and when exporting, the format of the xls file is collapsed, and i get the following error in the first some lines of the xls file:

```
Warning: Call-time pass-by-reference has been deprecated in /opt/maut/teszt/include/php_writeexcel/php_ole/class.ole_pps_root.php on line 305
```

On the line 305 there is:

```
array_push($raList, &$aThis[0]);
```

If I remove the **&** I cannot open the produced xls file, because Open Office says: **General Input/Outout error**

What could I do? Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply replace the `array_push()` code with the following:

```
$raList[] = & $aThis[0];
```

This will do the same thing, but won't produce the warning.